# How can i open files of different type with different algorithms in OpenFile dialog?

Tags: c#, file-io, openfiledialog

I want to open 2 type of Files(.txt and .dat) with an OpenFileDialog, each type of file should be opened with an different algorithm.
the OpenFile method gets the Stream of the File that i´m openning. but, can i get the type of that file? or is there another way to differentiate the files?

Comment: If you know the extension, you can guess the type.

Comment: Is this in Windows Forms? I note that its `OpenFileDialog.OpenFile` returns a `Stream` (which is unhelpful), while the Silverlight equivalent returns a `FileInfo` (which has the filename in it).

Comment: FileInfo also worked in Windows Forms thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we talk about winforms, then you have the filename available and you can check the extension before opening the file..

```
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(dialog.FileName);

    // do what you need
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks, it is a winform, but i got the extension with FileInfo